# Select one row from multiple tables that only exists in one of the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I have a mysql db that has two tables:

```
table1: 
id, stuff, more_stuff, something

table2:
id, stuff, more_stuff, something, even_more
```

Due to security/reliability reasons it is important that the ids of table 1 and table 2 are disjoint sets. This means that `table1.id` is never `table2.id`.

Edit: I dont know in which of the two tables the id=given_id is true.

Now I would like to `select * from table1 or table2 where id=given_id`. This would mean that only one of the tables has a row with id=given_id, and I would like to have that row returned. I cannot do that with a UNION, because my two tables are different length.

Sure I could do that with two statements, but that would require me to run two queries to the db.

Is there a way to select a single row from two tables, depending on where it exists in the tables?

Comment: UNION ALL the tables.

Comment: The corresponding error then is: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: How you know what id match given_id ? show us some example

Comment: That is the point, I dont know in which table the id is located :)

Comment: Add a dummy `null` as last column in the table1 select.

Comment: Well then forget about it. That security reason sound ridiculous. There are other way to secure db data than hiding ids

Comment: No its not hiding ids, there are multiple ids spread over two tables, and I dont know which table the id is in.

Comment: Again show us an example with data so we can understand the problem

Comment: It would be better to do this in the front end; run two queries. I always fail to understand people who seek to "only run one query" like it saves the database some time, when they then go looking for some truly horrible technique to join or union data that will waste even more time and computing resources.. databases are GOOD at running simple statements like "select * from table where indexedcolumn = value" and enterprise systems batter thousands of these kind of queries at their enterprise dbs every second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can still do a `UNION ALL`, like this one (you just have to use *named columns*):

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT 2 tbl, id, stuff, more_stuff, something, 
        even_more, and_more_stuff FROM table2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 tbl, id, stuff, more_stuff, something, 
        null,      null           FROM table1
) both WHERE id = MY_DESIRED_ID
```

I added a first column `tbl` with the table number so you will always know in which table you found the record in question.

Just changed it slightly, following @Caius's advice: having the broader table mentioned first saves you from supplying alias names in the columns list.

Comment: the 1 tbl column is genious :)

Comment: This is what I would do if I had a gun to my head and a manager refusing to let me just run two queries from the front end. I'd also put the table with the extra columns first

Comment: Two separate queries would even perform better than this. At least the WHERE condition should be applied to the both inner SELECT queries.

Answer (score 0):

FULL OUTER JOIN on id columns can help you I think.

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       coalesce(t1.stuff, t2.stuff) as stuff,
       coalesce(null, t2.even_more) as event_more
from t1 full outer join t2 
     on t1.id = t2.id
where coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) = MY_DESIRED_ID
```

Comment: He said the id aren't the same; why have the db waste its time trying to join data that cannot be joined? There's a risk this will perform like a dog, too

Comment: There is no `Full Outer Join` in MySQL !!